# String Contains Method C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a textbox that filters listbox results, and if I type it all caps it won't return anything, but all lower will.  I want to see if I missed something.  Here is what I am using.

Thanks

```
private void Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{

    var src = e.Item as Users;
    if (src == null)
        e.Accepted = false;
    //else if (src.Name!= null && !src.Name.Contains(Search))
    else if (src.Name!= null && !src.Name.ToLower().Contains(Search))
        e.Accepted = false;
}
```

Comment: The Property the Textbox is binding to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally [string.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) is implemented using [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425.aspx) and an [OrdinalCompare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) enum.
So your code could be changed to use a simple `IndexOf` without incurring the penalty required by the `ToLower` method that return a new copy of the original string.

```
if (src == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(src.Name))
    e.Accepted = false;
else if (src.Name.IndexOf(Search, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) < 0)
    e.Accepted = false;
```

[Strings are immutable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx), meaning that once created you can't change a string.
A method like `ToLower` actually creates a new string object to hold the new sequence of characters of the lower case kind, and that new object is returned.

Answer (score 2):

Change your Search to lower case also

```
        else if (src.Name!= null && !src.Name.ToLower().Contains(Search.ToLower()))
            e.Accepted = false;
```